# Why don't my confidence interval and p-value match for Kendall's Tau?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, p-value, kendall-tau

I'm trying to examine the relationship between two samples of ordinal scale values, by computing Kendall's Tau and its corresponding confidence interval (CI) and p-value.

I used the R function [cor.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/cor.test) (base package) to calculate the p-value:

```
> cor.test(x, y, alternative = "two.sided", method = "kendall")
```

which returns:

```
data:  x and y
z = -1.8504, p-value = 0.06425
alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
        tau 
-0.02553355
```

and I used the R function [kendall.ci](https://rdrr.io/cran/NSM3/man/kendall.ci.html) (NSM3 package) to calculate the CI:

```
> kendall.ci(x, y, alpha=0.05, type="t")
```

which returns:

```
1 - alpha = 0.95 two-sided CI for tau:
-0.042, -0.009
```

**The problem:** I'm having trouble interpreting and reporting these results, as I'd expect a 95% CI that does not include zero (the null-hypothesis value) to correspond to a p-value lower than 0.05, or conversely, a p-value above 0.05 with a 95% CI that includes zero.

**Re the data**: *x* and *y* both have 4,081 integer elements, no NaN's and 6 and 10 unique values, respectively (i.e. many "recurring values" or "ties"). I suspect the issue may be related to how these functions handle ties, but have yet to find the answer in the docs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code for `kendall.ci`, it seems to be using a U-statistic formula for the variance, which will be correct only for continuous distributions (though it should be an ok approximation more generally).Since you have a lot of ties and the $p$-value only just fails to match the confidence interval, I think that's the issue.

According to the documentation, the `kendall.ci` function has a `bootstrap` option, which should give you better results.